# Lambda layer pointing to s3 bucket another account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Looking for some help ...

​

I am creating a lambda layer (in Account A) and have pointed it to a zip file uploaded to an s3 bucket owner by another account (Account B). Both buckets are in the same region, but I am getting

​

Failed to create layer version: Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for mh-common-builds-dev-sg/decompress. S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied

​

I have already added a bucket policy in Account B with the appropriate permissions:

​

```
{

"Version":"2012-10-17",

"Statement":[

{

"Effect":"Allow",

"Principal":{

"AWS":"arn:aws:iam::AccountA:root"

},

"Action":[

"s3:*

],

"Resource":[

"arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucketName"

]

}

]

}
```

​

What am I doing wrong?

​

Thank you!

Comment: Could you try adding `"arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucketName"` to resource?

Comment: I'm glad it works out. Please consider accepting my answer below if you find it helpful. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on OP's feedback in comment, the following bucket policy works.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucketName/*",
        "arn:aws:s3:::AccountBBucketName"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: And in fact would likely work with *only* the resource ending in `/*` since Get*Object* needs object permissions rather than bucket permissions.